# Concatenate SQL Case Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, data-analysis

So I'm trying to combine values in each new column that I created in view with a case statement. How would I go about doing this?

```
SELECT
    PI.Patient_UID, PI.FirstName, PI.LastName, 
    AP.ApptStatus, AP.VisitPosted, CD.TotalDue,
    AP.Appointment_UID,
    CASE 
        WHEN AP.VisitPosted = 0 
            THEN 'Visit Posted Error' 
    END Error1,
    CASE 
        WHEN (CD.TotalDue IS NULL OR CD.TotalDue = '')  
            THEN 'Gross Charge Error' 
    END Error2
FROM
    vw_ODBC_pt_PatientInfo AS PI
INNER JOIN
    vw_ODBC_appts_Appointments AS AP ON AP.PatientFID = PI.Patient_UID
INNER JOIN
    vw_ODBC_actv_ChargeDetail AS CD ON CD.PatientFID = PI.Patient_UID 
WHERE
    AP.ApptStatus NOT IN ('10', '11', '12');
```

I need the new columns `Error1` and `Error2` to be concatenated as such:

```
Error1                Error2               ErrorsCombined
Visit Posted Error    Gross Charge Error    Visit Posted Error;Gross Charge Error
Visit Posted Error    NULL                  Visit Posted Error;
Visit Posted Error    NULL                  Visit Posted Error;
Visit Posted Error    NULL                  Visit Posted Error;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: @DaleK whoops, got confused by https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp ... they refer to it as a statement.

Comment: Yip, people have been trying to get them to correct that for years. But you should always reference the official docs anyway.

Comment: You can [edit] your question and correct it :)

Comment: All the Microsoft documentation on `CASE` references to it as an "expression" now, @mexicanRmy (or it should do, as a few of us all submitted pull requests to fix a load). W3Schools isn't documentation, and though it's "fine" for new users, it does have some bad/incorrect advice and language in there. For example, that link says `CASE` is like an `IF...ELSE`. A `Case` (`Switch`) **statement** *is* like an `IF...ELSE`, but a `CASE` *expression* is nothing like one. T-SQL, however, does not support `Switch` statements.

Comment: Neat-o, thx for your contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `APPLY` operator for the `Error1` and `Error2` expression. Make use of [concat_ws()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) which perform string concatenation with separator and it handle `NULL` value.

```
select PI.Patient_UID, 
       PI.FirstName, 
       PI.LastName, 
       AP.ApptStatus, 
       AP.VisitPosted, 
       CD.TotalDue,
       AP.Appointment_UID,
       e.Error1,
       e.Error2,
       concat_ws(';', e.Error1, e.Error2) as ErrorsCombined
from  vw_ODBC_pt_PatientInfo as PI
inner join vw_ODBC_appts_Appointments as AP on AP.PatientFID = PI.Patient_UID
inner join vw_ODBC_actv_ChargeDetail  as CD on CD.PatientFID = PI.Patient_UID 
cross apply
(
    select case when AP.VisitPosted = 0 
                then 'Visit Posted Error' 
                end as Error1,
           case when (CD.TotalDue is null or CD.TotalDue = '') 
                then 'Gross Charge Error' 
                end as Error2
) e
where AP.ApptStatus not in ('10','11','12');
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed to handle the null values.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your query to a common table expression and do the concatenation in the select that references the cte.

```
;with cte AS (
select  PI.Patient_UID, PI.FirstName, PI.LastName, AP.ApptStatus, AP.VisitPosted, CD.TotalDue, AP.Appointment_UID,
case when AP.VisitPosted = 0 then 'Visit Posted Error' end Error1,
case when (CD.TotalDue is null or CD.TotalDue = '') then 'Gross Charge Error' end Error2
from vw_ODBC_pt_PatientInfo as PI
inner join vw_ODBC_appts_Appointments as AP on AP.PatientFID = PI.Patient_UID
inner join vw_ODBC_actv_ChargeDetail as CD on CD.PatientFID = PI.Patient_UID 
where AP.ApptStatus not in ('10','11','12')
)

SELECT *,COALESCE(Error1+';','')+COALESCE(Error2,'') as ErrorsCombined
FROM cte
```

Comment: This is great! But doesn't handle the null values very well :( . If either Error1 or Error2 is null then the ErrorsCombined field results as null.

Comment: Edited my answer to add a COALESCE function.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you need to use **"+"** to splice characters.

```sql
SELECT Patient_UID,
         FirstName,
         LastName,
         ApptStatus,
         VisitPosted,
         TotalDue,
         Appointment_UID,
         Error1,
         Error2,
         Error1 + ';' + Error2 AS ErrorsCombined
FROM 
    (SELECT PI.Patient_UID,
         PI.FirstName,
         PI.LastName,
         AP.ApptStatus,
         AP.VisitPosted,
         CD.TotalDue,
         AP.Appointment_UID,
        CASE WHEN AP.VisitPosted = 0 THEN
        'Visit Posted Error'
        END Error1,
        CASE WHEN (CD.TotalDue is null
            OR CD.TotalDue = '') THEN
        'Gross Charge Error'
        END Error2
    FROM vw_ODBC_pt_PatientInfo AS PI
    INNER JOIN vw_ODBC_appts_Appointments AS AP
        ON AP.PatientFID = PI.Patient_UID
    INNER JOIN vw_ODBC_actv_ChargeDetail AS CD
        ON CD.PatientFID = PI.Patient_UID
    WHERE AP.ApptStatus NOT IN ('10','11','12')) A
```

Comment: I'll give this a try once I'm back home. Thank you for sharing!